# Unexpected token on Typescript Class when atribute is optional using "?"

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Suddenly VS Code started to point to optional attributes as wrong. I'm using typescript 4.1.2 and this wasn't happening before. It's just in the IDE though. The app runs normally without errors.

[image]

Comment: `I'm using typescript 3.8.3` I'm guessing that's what you use in your build. Can you double check that vscode is using it too? You should be able to see the typescript version on the bottom right of your VS Code window ([screenshot](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/typescript/compiling/version-status-bar.png))

Comment: You are right actually... It says 4.1.2

Comment: Well, an even newer version of typescript is not likely to be a problem... Best guess i have is that maybe you have some vs code extension installed which is tripping up.